# Store-and-forward failover solution for ServiceStack web services

Tags: rest, redis, servicestack, rabbitmq, message-queue

I am developing a customer account system for a chain of recycling centers in the [Northwest US](http://www.bottledropcenters.com).  One of our key features is that our customers can set up accounts that are credited with their [bottle deposit refunds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_deposit_legislation#United_States), instead of always disbursing cash.  Customers can also drop off bags of recyclables that are processed on-site and credited.  Each center runs near capacity and can physically process cans and bottles when offline, so we don't have a lot of leeway for IT infrastructure to shut down everything when the Internet goes out.

Basically, I've been asked to develop a customer account system that will allow credits from a retail center to be posted to accounts, even if telecommunications with our central server breaks down for a period of hours.  This will allow the center to keep processing and crediting customers when the pipes get clogged.  Certain transactions, like withdraws, do NOT need to occur in this situation, since we can't accurately get the customer's current balance.

We are a 100% Windows shop, and the IT manager and network admin don't want to get near anything *nix.  Each retail center has an on-premise dedicated Windows Server, so that seems like a logical place to start.

I'm a huge fan of [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net), and the REST-ful message-based paradigm seems like might work.  I'd create a "Credit" message and send it to the local server.  A message broker there would log the request and attempt to forward that message to the central server where it is processed.  In case the central server were down, I would rely on the MQ's reliable messaging protocol to hold on to it until telecommunications are restored.  The overall anticipated volume is 100s to low 1,000s of messages out of each center, so low by modern computing terms.

The [Redis MQ Client / Server](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis#redis-mq-client--server) for ServiceStack looks interesting, but since the Windows Redis server is explicitly labeled "prototype" and "not production quality", there is a 0% chance of being able to leverage it.

So, ultimately the questions are:

1. Is a reliable messaging system the right type of solution for this problem?  Are there other approaches I should consider?
2. Are there alternatives to Redis that play well with ServiceStack?  Is there a "production quality" NoSQL server replacement I can use on Windows?
3. I've looked briefly at RabbitMQ.  Might that be an option?  My Googling doesn't show any active integration between it and ServiceStack, so I'm leery of writing something from the ground up.
4. Ideally the overhead of my solution is low enough we can perform a synchronous update and return a "current balance" receipt to a customer if everything is working well.  Is this a realistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A production solution for running Redis on windows is to [run redis-server inside a Linux VM on windows with Vagrant](https://github.com/mythz/redis-windows).

There is current a [feature request to add more MQ Options](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/4459053-add-more-mq-options) to ServiceStack. Rabbit MQ is expected to be the next MQ adapter to be supported in future.

Comment: I'll look into Vagrant - might be an acceptable approach.  Awesome news about RabbitMQ - I look forward to seeing it in a future release.  Any chance you'll find someone to write up the x.x.# release notes?  Figuring out what has changed between 4.0.3 and 4.0.5, etc. is pretty difficult :(

Comment: @jklemmack Vagrant simplifies configuring, provisioning and starting VMs. If it's easier to manage, you can skip Vagrant and just run redis-server in your preferred VM environment.

Comment: Looks like RabbitMQ is going to fit the bill, and the great folks at ServiceStack just published initial integration!  w00t

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up, MS Open Tech has released a "production-ready" native implementation of Redis 2.8.9.  [GitHub link](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis).